# Perl XML Parsing

Tags: xml, perl

I am using XML::Simple to parse a XML file. The output is a hash.(using Data::Dumper)

Sample code , XML file are given below with output.

Perl code:

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

$xml = new XML::Simple;

$data = $xml->XMLin("spam.xml");

print Dumper($data);
```

XML file contents (input to parser)::

```
<Attach_request>
    <Protocol_discriminator>
        <name> Protocol_discriminator </name>
        <attribute> Mandatory </attribute>
        <type> nibble </type>
        <value> 7 </value>
        <min> 0 </min>
        <max> F </max>
    </Protocol_discriminator>
    <Security_header>
        <name> Security_header </name>
        <attribute> Mandatory </attribute>
        <type> nibble </type>
        <value> 7 </value>
        <min> 0 </min>
        <max> F </max>
    </Security_header>
    <Security_header1>
        <name> Security_header </name>
        <attribute> Mandatory </attribute>
        <type> nibble </type>
        <value> 7 </value>
        <min> 0 </min>
        <max> F </max>
    </Security_header1>
    <Security_header2>
        <name> Security_header </name>
        <attribute> Mandatory </attribute>
        <type> nibble </type>
        <value> 7 </value>
        <min> 0 </min>
        <max> F </max>
    </Security_header2>
    <Security_header3>
        <name> Security_header </name>
        <attribute> Mandatory </attribute>
        <type> nibble </type>
        <value> 7 </value>
        <min> 0 </min>
        <max> F </max>
    </Security_header3>
</Attach_request>
```

Output::

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Security_header3' => {
                                'attribute' => ' Mandatory ',
                                'min' => ' 0 ',
                                'value' => ' 7 ',
                                'max' => ' F ',
                                'name' => ' Security_header ',
                                'type' => ' nibble '
                              },
          'Protocol_discriminator' => {
                                      'attribute' => ' Mandatory ',
                                      'min' => ' 0 ',
                                      'value' => ' 7 ',
                                      'max' => ' F ',
                                      'name' => ' Protocol_discriminator ',
                                      'type' => ' nibble '
                                    },
          'Security_header2' => {
                                'attribute' => ' Mandatory ',
                                'min' => ' 0 ',
                                'value' => ' 7 ',
                                'max' => ' F ',
                                'name' => ' Security_header ',
                                'type' => ' nibble '
                              },
          'Security_header' => {
                               'attribute' => ' Mandatory ',
                               'min' => ' 0 ',
                               'value' => ' 7 ',
                               'max' => ' F ',
                               'name' => ' Security_header ',
                               'type' => ' nibble '
                             },
          'Security_header1' => {
                                'attribute' => ' Mandatory ',
                                'min' => ' 0 ',
                                'value' => ' 7 ',
                                'max' => ' F ',
                                'name' => ' Security_header ',
                                'type' => ' nibble '
                              }
        };
```

My other question is:

1. Is there any way i can manintain the order of the output, the same i gave in the input XML file ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see the documentation of [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm), it states that

**XML::Simple is able to present a simple API because it makes some assumptions on your behalf**. These include:

1. You're not interested in text content consisting only of whitespace
2. **You don't mind that when things get slurped into a hash the order is lost**
3. You don't want fine-grained control of the formatting of generated XML
4. You would never use a hash key that was not a legal XML element name
5. You don't need help converting between different encodings.

For tree-based parsing, you could choose between the 'Perlish' approach of **XML::Twig** and more standards based **DOM implementations** - preferably one with XPath support.

see also '[**Perl-XML FAQ**](http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/)' for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

*Some* of the ordering would be retained if you turned off the KeyAttr option. If you do decide to stick with XML::Simple and mess around with different settings then you really ought to have a quick read through this article:

- [Does your XML::Simple code pass the strict test?](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=218480)

A better approach would be to ditch XML::Simple altogether as advised in this article:

- [Stepping up from XML::Simple to XML::LibXML](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=490846)

**Edit (9 years later)**: I've subsequently created a tutorial site called [Perl XML::LibXML by Example](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) that introduces the XML::LibXML library and XPath using lots of examples.  XML::LibXML is a **much** better module for working with XML than XML::Simple and using it is generally simpler due to the power of XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if it is possible with XML::Simple (perhaps you'd have to sort hash keys in some way). You can also use XML::DOM and enumerate through child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aLibXML).